# How to set relative base URL in angular

Tags: angular, relative-url

Hi I checked answers around but none worked for me as expected, basically the problem is that I want to set my URLs protocol and domain name dynamically in angular service.
Here's my code for example:

```
baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/test/rest/employees/'
```

if i use this form as seen in other posts it doesn't work:

```
baseUrl: string = '/test/rest/emplyoees/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a `proxy.conf.json` file.

```
{
    "/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Angular checks for this file and automatically appends it to the api requests.

Comment: can you give a link for a good documentation how to configure it because i made the file and added it in ```angular.json``` but still not working

Comment: I hope this works for you.
(https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/angular-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-6fb37ef0d025)Link

Comment: well it works but the problem is still there that i have to set the domain manually, not in the service but still have to set it everytime the servers url changes

Comment: In Angular 17, you may need to use `/**` instead of just `/`.